# Using NLog with asp-net layout renderers in AspNet vNext (MVC 6)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nlog

I am trying to integrate NLog in AspNet 5 (or using the new name AspNet Core 1.0) web app. Not sure if it is possible at all but I want to log the currently logged in user.
This is my NLog config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile"
            xsi:type="File"
            fileName="file.txt"
            layout="${longdate}|${message}|${identity}|${aspnet-user-identity}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="WebApplication2.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

The thing is that I get

> System.ArgumentException: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'aspnet-user-identity'

My project.json file looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    .....
    "NLog.Framework.logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "NLog": "4.4.0-alpha1",
    "NLog.Config": "4.3.0-beta1",
    "NLog.Extended": "4.0.0-rc",
    "NLog.Web": "4.1.0"
  },
```

Maybe I am missing something, or it is not yet supported by NLog ?

**EDIT:** I found out that auto load of extensions is not currently supported. So, I have to modify my NLog.config like:

```
 <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web"/>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extended"/>
  </extensions>
```

But now I get blank input for the current user. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [internal log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting#internal-logging) will give some more info why loading the extension failed.

There are also other ways to load the extensions,  the [assemblyFile attribute](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/examples/web/config4.nlog) and programmatically:

```
//target
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.Targets
                        .RegisterDefinition("MyFirst", typeof(MyNamespace.MyFirstTarget));

//layout renderer
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers
                        .RegisterDefinition("hello-world", typeof(MyNamespace.HelloWorldLayoutRenderer ));
```

Edit: did some tests. This works in loading the assembly:

`<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web" />
  </extensions>`

But too bad [NLog.Web isn't ASP.NET 5 compatible, yet](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/29). We can't use `HttpContext.Current` there.

**edit:** an ASP.NET 5 compatible version of NLog.Web is now available! See [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.ASPNET5/)

Comment: Yes, I checked directly in the repo in github. As soon as I saw that it uses HttpContext.Current, realized that won't be able to use it. 
Anyway, as a temporary solution I will create my own ILogger implementation that uses internally NLog. Thus I will have more control and I would be able to pass whatever I want.